# Fancytree: Remove nodes without children

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I want to remove selected nodes and move all children to it's place.
I use code:

```
ref = $('#tree').fancytree("getTree"),
searchIDs = ref.getSelectedNodes();

searchIDs.forEach(function(node){
 $children = node.children;
 if ($children!==null)node.parent.addChildren($children,node.getNextSibling());
 node.remove();
});
```

Where #tree is div with ul\li. If Nodes > 1 I have error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addChildren' of null "  and only one node is removed.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use [node.moveTo()](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#moveTo) instead:

```
var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree"),
    selNodes = tree.getSelectedNodes();

selNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    while( node.hasChildren() ) {
        node.getFirstChild().moveTo(node.parent, "child");
    }
    node.remove();
});
```

Note that you might have to add some special handling when selected nodes are descendants of other selected nodes, e.g. iterate reverse or discard nested nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the above solution.